# why select name from v$database showing only one database?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am learning oracle 10g in school. In the lab we created a db called ORCL. After the lab I successfully created 2 more database. one is HORCL2016 and HORCL 2017. I add both of them on Oracle enterprise manager console. Now Both are showing in the tree. I can connect or disconnect them from the tree. I checked both client/server tnsname.ora and both DB is present.Now when I do  :

```
select name from v$database
```

it only shows ORCL. What could be wrong? Any help?

[image]

Comment: You can only be connected to one database at a time.  Apparently, your session is currently connected to the database named ORCL.  If you connect to a different database that has a different name, you'd get a different result in `v$database`.

Comment: do  I need to change spfile to connect to different database?

Comment: If you really have three databases, then you have three spfiles (assuming all three use spfiles rather than pfiles).  You say that you have three different TNS entries.  You would need to connect to a different alias to connect to a different database.  Assuming that you actually created different databases with different names rather than, say, creating multiple services for a single database.

Comment: all alias are different. One is ORCL, another HORCL and HORCL2[ server tnsname.]

Comment: Assuming that you have three different databases (rather than three TNS aliases that all point to the same database or three TNS aliases that all point to different services for the same database), and assuming that the database name matches the TNS alias, if you connect to the HORCL TNS alias, `v$database` would report a name of `HORCL`.  If you connect to the HORCL2 TNS alias, `v$database` would report a name of `HORCL2`.

Comment: ok forget about everything  . All databases are maintained username sys or sysdba. Password is: safe. Give me a simple script to connect to HORCL

Comment: Assuming you use `SQL*Plus`, `sqlplus username/password@TNSAlias`.

Answer (score 1):

The `v$database` view has 1 line for some of the information about the database to which you are connected. You can only connect to 1 database at a time.